# Why Triple Linked List does not exist?

Tags: data-structures

I would like to know why triple linked list does not exist but double linked list exist ?

Unlike double linked list why can't we use another pointer in the code to store another address to point new node ?

Comment: What would it point to?

Comment: You could, but it might then be called something other than a "list" because the data structure would probably do more than give a linear order.  I guess one reason you might have a third pointer might be to point to the start of the list, if there was a reason to be able to get to the start (or end) of the list without traversing it. I'd guess there's a limited use for something like that, because I can't recall coming across anyone using something like that (or if I did, I didn't consider it anything noteworthy - just another pointer that could be used for something).

Comment: You might also find the [ternary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_tree) of interest.

Comment: A "triple-linked list" is called a binary tree, not a list. (As long as you don't introduce cycles.) The third pointer in the node fundamentally changes the nature of the data structure. On the other hand if you want to use the third pointer for _data_, then it's not a matter of the structure any more - change the _data_ that the node is carrying to include the extra information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is a linear data structure. You can go forward (a singly-linked list), or forward and back (a doubly-linked list). There is no third pointer in a one-dimensional data structure because it would be redundant. In which direction would it point?

A [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), which also has two pointers per node, is a two-dimensional data structure. The pointers reference the left or right child nodes. It's also common to have a third pointer, which references the parent node.

You can add as many node pointers as you like. For example, there are [ternary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_tree), [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [octrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), and all manner of custom n-dimensional data structures. They're not called *lists*, though, because list implies a sequential structure.

Comment: I got to admit. This was VERY good answer.